# How to extract data from a thermal printer from an old machine

Tags: printing, interface, extract, escpos

I have an old machine that takes measurements of an object and prints the data to a inbuilt thermal printer. I am looking for a solution to extract this data so that it can go directly into a database.

Is there any way to hack into the esc/pos printer hardware and extract this binary data to a pc and then decode it to text?

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure ist uses ESC/POS?  How is the printer connected to the machine?

Comment: I assume its a ecs/pos printer. The printer is connected inside the machine. I will have to open it up to check.

Comment: Did you find out if it is serial, parallel, or, USB connected printer?